# How to select table cell in the if function in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-2019

I have a stock management table in excel sheet. Demo here:
[Demo photo of this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7MlC.png)

I want to create a code in VBA that comes **In stock** column and will test the whole cells. If any cell.Value < 2 and >0 then go to 4 cells backward take the value of this cell and show a message box
"backward cell.value and *stock not available*".

---

I tired to make this please help me.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far and then people can help you revise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to select table cells, here is one'

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckStock()
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, i As Integer, p As Integer
    Dim s As String

    With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
        i = .ListColumns("In stock").Index
        p = .ListColumns("Product Name").Index

        For r = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            n = .DataBodyRange(r, i)
            If n > 0 And n < 2 Then
                s = s & vbCrLf & .DataBodyRange(r, p)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Len(s) > 0 then 
        MsgBox "Products not available :" & s, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But here was a problem Msgbox is outside of the function. So, Msgbox is all time enable to work. But I want to enable Msgbox when stock is under 2. Otherwise, Msgbox is disabled.

Comment: @saiful If for example there are 3 items out of stock do you want the msgbox alert 3 times ?